# First appearance in Stern's Diatomic Sequence

Tags: algorithm, oeis

You get an integer n and you need to find the index of its first appearance in Stern's Diatomic Sequence.

The sequence is defined like this:

```
a[0]     = 0
a[1]     = 1
a[2*i]   = a[i]
a[2*i+1] = a[i] + a[i+1]
```

See [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SternsDiatomicSeries.html).

Because n can be up to 400000, it's not a good idea to brute-force it, especially since the time limit is 4000 ms.

The sequence is pretty odd: first occurrence of 8 is 21, but first occurrence of 6 is 33.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Maybe this might help: [OEIS](http://oeis.org/A020946)

Comment: Is pre-calc an option? Recursion with memoization took less than a minute on my machine to find all 400000 numbers in Stern sequence (indices are less than a billion).

Comment: It is an option. The problem is that you don't have to compute the indices, you have to see where that big number appears first. I computed the first 10M numbers and the sequence barely got to about 20K, without encompassing all the natural numbers up to 20K.

Comment: Not in any trivial way, no.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We can easily solve for the first occurrence of a number in the range of 400000 in under four seconds:

```
Prelude Diatomic> firstDiatomic 400000
363490989
(0.03 secs, 26265328 bytes)
Prelude Diatomic> map firstDiatomic [400000 .. 400100]
[363490989,323659475,580472163,362981813,349334091,355685483,346478235,355707595
,291165867,346344083,347155797,316314293,576398643,315265835,313171245,355183267
,315444051,315970205,575509833,311741035,340569429,313223987,565355925,296441165
,361911645,312104147,557145429,317106853,323637939,324425077,610613547,311579309
,316037811,311744107,342436533,348992869,313382235,325406123,355818699,312128723
,347230875,324752171,313178421,312841811,313215645,321754459,576114987,325793195
,313148763,558545581,355294101,359224397,345462093,307583675,355677549,312120731
,341404245,316298389,581506779,345401947,312109779,316315061,315987123,313447771
,361540179,313878107,304788843,325765547,316036275,313731751,355635795,312035947
,346756533,313873883,349358379,357393763,559244877,313317739,325364139,312128107
,580201947,358182323,314944173,357403987,584291115,312158827,347448723,363246413
,315935571,349386085,315929427,312137323,357247725,313207657,320121429,356954923
,557139285,296392013,576042123,311726765,296408397]
(2.45 secs, 3201358192 bytes)
```

The key to it is the Calkin-Wilf tree.

Starting from the fraction `1/1`, it is built by the rule that for a node with the fraction `a/b`, its left child carries the fraction `a/(a+b)`, and its right child the fraction `(a+b)/b`.

```
                        1/1
                       /   \
                      /     \
                     /       \
                  1/2         2/1
                 /   \       /   \
               1/3   3/2   2/3   3/1
```

etc. The diatomic sequence (starting at index 1) is the sequence of numerators of the fractions in the Calkin-Wilf tree, when that is traversed level by level, each level from left to right.

If we look at the tree of indices

```
                         1
                        / \
                       /   \
                      /     \
                     2       3
                    / \     / \
                   4   5   6   7
                  / \ 
                 8   9 ...
```

we can easily verify that the node at index `k` in the Calkin-Wilf tree carries the fraction `a[k]/a[k+1]` by induction.

That is obviously true for `k = 1` (`a[1] = a[2] = 1`), and from then on,

- for `k = 2*j` we have the left child of the node with index `j`, so the fraction is `a[j]/(a[j]+a[j+1])` and `a[k] = a[j]` and `a[k+1] = a[j] + a[j+1]` are the defining equations of the sequence.
- for `k = 2*j+1` we have the right child of the node with index `j`, so the fraction is `(a[j]+a[j+1])/a[j+1]` and that is `a[k]/a[k+1]` again by the defining equations.

All positive reduced fractions occur exactly once in the Calkin-Wilf tree (left as an exercise for the reader), hence all positive integers occur in the diatomic sequence.

We can find the node in the Calkin-Wilf tree from the index by following the binary representation of the index, from the most significant bit to the least, for a 1-bit we go to the right child and for a 0-bit to the left. (For that, it is nice to augment the Calkin-Wilf tree with a node `0/1` whose right child is the `1/1` node, so that we need have a step for the most significant set bit of the index.)

Now, that doesn't yet help very much to solve the problem at hand.

But, let us first solve a related problem: For a reduced fraction `p/q`, determine its index.

Suppose that `p > q`. Then we know that `p/q` is a right child, and its parent is `(p-q)/q`. If also `p-q > q`, we have again a right child, whose parent is `(p - 2*q)/q`. Continuing, if

```
p = a*q + b, 1 <= b < q
```

then we reach the `p/q` node from the `b/q` node by going to the right child `a` times.

Now we need to find a node whose numerator is smaller than its denominator. That is of course the left child of its parent. The parent of `b/q` is `b/(q-b)` then. If

```
q = c*b + d, 1 <= d < b
```

we have to go to the left child `c` times from the node `b/d` to reach `b/q`.

And so on.

We can find the way from the root (`1/1`) to the `p/q` node using the continued fraction (I consider only simple continued fractions here) expansion of `p/q`. Let `p > q` and

```
p/q = [a_0, a_1, ..., a_r,1]
```

the continued fraction expansion of `p/q` ending in `1`.

- If `r` is even, then go to the right child `a_r` times, then to the left `a_(r-1)` times, then to the right child ... then `a_1` times to the left child, and finally `a_0` times to the right.
- If `r` is odd, then first go to the left child `a_r` times, then `a_(r-1)` times to the right ... then `a_1` times to the left child, and finally `a_0` times to the right.

For `p < q`, we must end going to the left, hence start going to the left for even `r` and start going to the right for odd `r`.

We have thus found a close connection between the binary representation of the index and the continued fraction expansion of the fraction carried by the node via the path from the root to the node.

Let the run-length-encoding of the index `k` be

```
[c_1, c_2, ..., c_j]           (all c_i > 0)
```

i.e. the binary representation of `k` starts with `c_1` ones, followed by `c_2` zeros, then `c_3` ones etc., and ending with `c_j`

- ones, if `k` is odd - hence `j` is also odd;
- zeros, if `k` is even - hence `j` is also even.

Then `[c_j, c_(j-1), ..., c_2, c_1]` is the continued fraction expansion of `a[k]/a[k+1]` whose length has the same parity as `k` (every rational has exactly two continued fraction expansions, one with odd length, the other with even length).

The RLE gives the path from the `0/1` node above `1/1` to `a[k]/a[k+1]`. The length of the path is

1. the number of bits necessary to represent `k`, and
2. the sum of the partial quotients in the continued fraction expansion.

Now, to find the index of the first occurrence of `n > 0` in the diatomic sequence, we first observe that the smallest index must necessarily be odd, since `a[k] = a[k/2]` for even `k`. Let the smallest index be `k = 2*j+1`. Then

1. the length of the RLE of `k` is odd,
2. the fraction at the node with index `k` is `a[2*j+1]/a[2*j+2] = (a[j] + a[j+1])/a[j+1]`, hence it is a right child.

So the smallest index `k` with `a[k] = n` corresponds to the left-most ending of all the shortest paths to a node with numerator `n`.

The shortest paths correspond to the continued fraction expansions of `n/m`, where `0 < m <= n` is coprime to `n` [the fraction must be reduced] with the smallest sum of the partial quotients.

What kind of length do we need to expect? Given a continued fraction `p/q = [a_0, a_1, ..., a_r]` with `a_0 > 0` and sum

```
s = a_0 + ... + a_r
```

the numerator `p` is bounded by `F(s+1)` and the denominator `q` by `F(s)`, where `F(j)` is the `j`-th Fibonacci number. The bounds are sharp, for `a_0 = a_1 = ... = a_r = 1` the fraction is `F(s+1)/F(s)`.

So if `F(t) < n <= F(t+1)`, the sum of the partial quotients of the continued fraction expansion (either of the two) is `>= t`. Often there is an `m` such that the sum of the partial quotients of the continued fraction expansion of `n/m` is exactly `t`, but not always:

```
F(5) = 5 < 6 <= F(6) = 8
```

and the continued fraction expansions of the two reduced fractions `6/m` with `0 < m <= 6` are

```
6/1 = [6]          (alternatively [5,1])
6/5 = [1,4,1]      (alternatively [1,5])
```

with sum of the partial quotients 6. However, the smallest possible sum of partial quotients is never much larger (the largest I'm aware of is `t+2`).

The continued fraction expansions of `n/m` and `n/(n-m)` are closely related. Let's assume that `m < n/2`, and let

```
n/m = [a_0, a_1, ..., a_r]
```

Then `a_0 >= 2`,

```
(n-m)/m = [a_0 - 1, a_1, ..., a_r]
```

and since

```
n/(n-m) = 1 + m/(n-m) = 1 + 1/((n-m)/m)
```

the continued fraction expansion of `n/(n-m)` is

```
n/(n-m) = [1, a_0 - 1, a_1, ..., a_r]
```

In particular, the sum of the partial quotients is the same for both.

Unfortunately, I'm not aware of a way to find the `m` with the smallest sum of partial quotients without brute force, so the algorithm is (I assume `n > 2`

1. for `0 < m < n/2` coprime to `n`, find the continued fraction expansion of `n/m`, collecting the ones with the smallest sum of the partial quotients (the usual algorithm produces expansions whose last partial quotient is `> 1`, we assume that).
2. Adjust the found continued fraction expansions [those are not large in number] it the following way:

   - if the CF `[a_0, a_1, ..., a_r]` has even length, convert it to `[a_0, a_1, ..., a_(r-1), a_r - 1, 1]`
   - otherwise, use `[1, a_0 - 1, a_1, ..., a_(r-1), a_r - 1, 1]`

   (that chooses the one between `n/m` and `n/(n-m)` leading to the smaller index)
3. reverse the continued fractions to obtain the run-length-encodings of the corresponding indices
4. choose the smallest among them.

In step 1, it is useful to use the smallest sum found so far to short-cut.

Code (Haskell, since that's easiest):

```hs
module Diatomic (diatomic, firstDiatomic, fuscs) where

import Data.List

strip :: Int -> Int -> Int
strip p = go
  where
    go n = case n `quotRem` p of
             (q,r) | r == 0    -> go q
                   | otherwise -> n

primeFactors :: Int -> [Int]
primeFactors n
    | n < 1             = error "primeFactors: non-positive argument"
    | n == 1            = []
    | n `rem` 2 == 0    = 2 : go (strip 2 (n `quot` 2)) 3
    | otherwise         = go n 3
      where
        go 1 _ = []
        go m p
            | m < p*p   = [m]
            | r == 0    = p : go (strip p q) (p+2)
            | otherwise = go m (p+2)
              where
                (q,r) = m `quotRem` p

contFracLim :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Maybe [Int]
contFracLim = go []
  where
    go acc lim n d = case n `quotRem` d of
                       (a,b) | lim < a -> Nothing
                             | b == 0  -> Just (a:acc)
                             | otherwise -> go (a:acc) (lim - a) d b

fixUpCF :: [Int] -> [Int]
fixUpCF [a]
    | a < 3     = [a]
    | otherwise = [1,a-2,1]
fixUpCF xs
    | even (length xs) = case xs of
                           (1:_) -> fixEnd xs
                           (a:bs) -> 1 : (a-1) : bs
    | otherwise        = case xs of
                           (1:_) -> xs
                           (a:bs) -> 1 : fixEnd ((a-1):bs)

fixEnd :: [Int] -> [Int]
fixEnd [a,1] = [a+1]
fixEnd [a] = [a-1,1]
fixEnd (a:bs) = a : fixEnd bs
fixEnd _ = error "Shouldn't have called fixEnd with an empty list"

cfCompare :: [Int] -> [Int] -> Ordering
cfCompare (a:bs) (c:ds) = case compare a c of
                            EQ -> cfCompare ds bs
                            cp -> cp

fibs :: [Integer]
fibs = 0 : 1 : zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibs)

toNumber :: [Int] -> Integer
toNumber = foldl' ((+) . (*2)) 0 . concat . (flip (zipWith replicate) $ cycle [1,0])

fuscs :: Integer -> (Integer, Integer)
fuscs 0 = (0,1)
fuscs 1 = (1,1)
fuscs n = case n `quotRem` 2 of
            (q,r) -> let (a,b) = fuscs q
                     in if r == 0
                          then (a,a+b)
                          else (a+b,b)
diatomic :: Integer -> Integer
diatomic = fst . fuscs

firstDiatomic :: Int -> Integer
firstDiatomic n
    | n < 0     = error "Diatomic sequence has no negative terms"
    | n < 2     = fromIntegral n
    | n == 2    = 3
    | otherwise = toNumber $ bestCF n

bestCF :: Int -> [Int]
bestCF n = check [] estimate start
  where
    pfs = primeFactors n
    (step,ops) = case pfs of
                   (2:xs) -> (2,xs)
                   _      -> (1,pfs)
    start0 = (n-1) `quot` 2
    start | even n && even start0 = start0 - 1
          | otherwise             = start0
    eligible k = all ((/= 0) . (k `rem`)) ops
    estimate = length (takeWhile (<= fromIntegral n) fibs) + 2
    check candidates lim k
        | k < 1 || n `quot` k >= lim = if null candidates
                                         then check [] (2*lim) start
                                         else minimumBy cfCompare candidates
        | eligible k = case contFracLim lim n k of
                         Nothing -> check candidates lim (k-step)
                         Just cf -> let s = sum cf
                                    in if s < lim
                                         then check [fixUpCF cf] s (k - step)
                                         else check (fixUpCF cf : candidates) lim (k-step)
        | otherwise = check candidates lim (k-step)
```

Comment: +1: Nice, I think your numerator,denominator are the same as my b,a but this answer gives a clearer understanding and faster algorithm.  (@dragostis: In my opinion this should be marked as the best answer)

Comment: Nice work!  I'm curious if you'd be willing to share the hardware/setup details you got those timings on.  I ran this under Windows on a 1.6Ghz and got firstDiatomic 400000 => 2.75 secs and map firstDiatomic [400000 .. 400100] => (452.25 secs, 31745121676 bytes); using fpcomplete.com the 400000 took 1.56009 and the map timed out...

Comment: The map on fpcomplete.com completed in and the map took 242.147s

Comment: @Thell A pretty standard 2.3 GHz Core i5, running 64-bit Linux. Of course, I have compiled the module with optimisations, running interpreted code is slow here too. Though at 1.21 resp 189.4 seconds not as slow as on your box.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, now I feel pretty good about a solution I'm working with via R and Rcpp that is getting timings of 7ms for 400000 and 2.4s for the [400000..400100] map.  Just for grins 800000..800020 took 2.6s

Comment: The prime numbers are killers for processing the coprimes

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you read this [letter from Dijkstra](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~EWD/transcriptions/EWD05xx/EWD570.html) which explains an alternative way of computing this function via:

```
n, a, b := N, 1, 0;
do n ≠ 0 and even(n) → a, n:= a + b, n/2
             odd(n) → b, n:= b + a, (n-1)/2
od {b = fusc(N)}
```

This starts with a,b=1,0 and effectively uses successive bits of N (from least to most significant) to increase a and b, the final result being the value of b.

The index of the first appearance of a particular value for b can therefore be computed via finding the smallest n for which this iteration will result in that value of b.

One method for finding this smallest n is to use [A* search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%2a_search_algorithm) where the cost is the value of n.  The efficiency of the algorithm will be determined by your choice of heuristic.

For the heuristic, I would recommend noting that:

1. the final value will always be a multiple of the gcd(a,b) (this can be used to rule out some nodes that can never produce the target)
2. b always increases
3. there is a maximum (exponential) rate at which b can increase (the rate depends on the current value of a)

EDIT

Here is some example Python code to illustrate the A* approach.

```
from heapq import *

def gcd(a,b):
    while a:
        a,b=b%a,a
    return b

def heuristic(node,goal):
    """Estimate least n required to make b==goal"""
    n,a,b,k = node
    if b==goal: return n
    # Otherwise needs to have at least one more bit set
    # Improve this heuristic to make the algorithm faster
    return n+(1<<k)

def diatomic(goal):
    """Return index of first appearance of n in Stern's Diatomic sequence"""
    start=0,1,0,0
    f_score=[] # This is used as a heap
    heappush(f_score, (0,start) )
    while 1:
        s,node = heappop(f_score)
        n,a,b,k = node
        if b==goal:
            return n
        for node in [ (n,a+b,b,k+1),(n+(1<<k),a,b+a,k+1) ]:
            n2,a2,b2,k2 = node
            if b2<=goal and (goal%gcd(a2,b2))==0:
                heappush(f_score,(heuristic(node,goal),node))

print [diatomic(n) for n in xrange(1,10)]
```

Comment: Can you be a bit more explicit on how you would apply A*? It's not really trivial to see the search tree from this expression.

Comment: The solution appears sane, but I'm still not convinced it will reach any solution in the range 400000 in under 4s.

Comment: i'm not too familiar with algorithmic notation -- what does `od` mean (in `od {b = fusc(N)}`)?

Comment: That's where the do block ends.